# How to calculate the probability distribution for the types of balls which we draw from a box? (Multivariate hypergeometric distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, combinations

I came across the following problem:

Assume there are 6 different types of balls in a box. Each type of ball has three copies, meaning there are 18 total balls in our box.

We now randomly take out 9 balls and do not put them back.

My question is: Is there a formula for the probability distribution which shows how many **types** of balls are still in our box?

I know that the "worst" case would be: We draw 3 types, each 3 times. Meaning that only 3 types out of the 6 would be left in the box.

The "best" case would be that we pick 3 types twice, and 3 types once, meaning that all types are still left in the box.

But I do not yet know how to describe this as a probability distribution, i.e. e.g. the probability that we have 5 out of the 6 types, or 4 out of the 6 types still left in the box. I tried with a probability tree, but that did not give me an idea of a formula.

Do you know how to get a formula?

Comment: Consider adding over the various cases in the mutlivariate hypergeometric distribution.  As an aside, getting the actual probability distribution itself may be messy, but finding the expected value is trivial using linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the problem by cases, which are (up to permutations):
$$\begin{array}{l|c|l}
\#&\text{state}&\text{cardinality},\  N_i\\
\hline
1&3-3-3-0-0-0&\binom63\binom33^3\\
2&3-3-2-1-0-0&\binom62\binom33^2\binom41\binom32^1\binom31\binom31^1\\
3&3-3-1-1-1-0&\binom62\binom33^2\binom43\binom31^3\\
4&3-2-2-2-0-0&\binom61\binom33^1\binom53\binom32^3\\
5&3-2-2-1-1-0&\binom61\binom33^1\binom52\binom32^2\binom32\binom31^2\\
6&3-2-1-1-1-1&\binom61\binom33^1\binom51\binom32^1\binom44\binom31^4\\
7&2-2-2-2-1-0&\binom64\binom32^4\binom21\binom31^1\\
8&2-2-2-1-1-1&\binom63\binom32^3\binom33\binom31^3\\
\end{array}$$

From this table we have:
$$
p(3)=\frac{N_1}N;\quad p(4)=\frac{N_2+N_3}N;\quad p(5)=\frac{N_4+N_5+N_6}N;\quad p(6)=\frac{N_7+N_8}N,
$$
where $N=\binom{18}9$ is the total number of ways to choose $9$ balls.